# Why is my bash script not printing the final line?

Tags: bash, shell, text

I have a simple bash script that does this:

```
while IFS= read line; do
  echo "$line"
done < company/employee.txt
```

The contents of the text file are:

```
id,name,height,age
bob,raph,188,35
jordan,billy,188,35
```

But the script only prints

```
id,name,height,age
bob,raph,188,35
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What is output of `cat -A file`?

Comment: Why do you have the `IFS=` in place?

Comment: @anubhava it says -A is an illegal option

Comment: @hek2mgl yep I've tried that

Comment: I've asked *why*

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry just because I thought without it might the issue- I've found the answer though it's because I needed to have a new line at the end of the file, thanks for hte help!